# All the others (not this)

Tags: jquery, this

I have different divs repeated in the same page. This is the example simplified: 
http://jsfiddle.net/8gPCE/16/

What I try to do is:
 
- Click on a green and only his red fadeOut
- The other red fadeIn
- And when I click to anywhere else like the background all the red fadeIn

I have been hour trying and I don't find the 3 things at the same time.

Something like this doesn't work.(and I just try the 2 first things):

```
$(function(){

    $(".green").click(function() {
        $(this).siblings(".red").fadeOut("slow");
        $(this).parent().not(this).children(".red").fadeIn("slow");
    });

})
```

Comment: There's a fault in you fiddle it should be $('.green').click instead of #green

Comment: bruv you got class green :) and you are using #green as an id use $('.green) and voilla = http://jsfiddle.net/m42wd/2/ have a nice one, cheers!

Comment: Yes, there was an error in the fiddle, I already updated it. Thank you (but this was not the important problem, the rest of the question is the same)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should handle all issues

```
$(".green").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).siblings(".red").fadeOut("slow");
    $('.green').not(this).siblings(".red").fadeIn("slow");
});

$(document).click(function() {
   $('.red').fadeIn();
});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/8gPCE/11/

Comment: This solution is great. Very clear and simple. It helps me because now I understand what was wrong with my code. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You mustuse a class selector and do something like

```
//when you click on an element with class green
$(".green").click(function() {
    //select his red sibling
    var sib =  $(this).siblings(".red");
    //fade it out
    sib.fadeOut("slow");
    //select all red elements that are not the red sibling and fade them in
    $(".red").not(sib).fadeIn("slow");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8gPCE/2/

To implement also the other behaviour, add

```
$(window).on("click", function(e){
    if(!$(e.target).hasClass('green')){
        $(".red").fadeIn("slow");
    }
});
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/8gPCE/7/

Comment: Your code works fine in the fiddle but when I put it in an ordinary html, copy paste, to study it, the first part works fine but the part when I click the $(window) doesn't work. I don't know why?

Comment: @Narcís that's weird!In any case if it works use the code by Gaby which is good too! :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should change your id selector to the class one :
 `$("#green")` to `$(".green")`.
Another thing to have in mind is that these 2 expressions ( `$(this).siblings()` and `$(this).parent().children()`) mean the same thing, which means that your code can be translated to :

```
 $(".green").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings(".red").fadeOut("slow").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Comment: - Yes is true, in my first version there was the mistake to put #green and it should be .green. Thank you.

Comment: - The other part, doesn't solve what I am asking. I tried to do 3 different things. Perhaps I did no explain well: 1- Click on a green and _only his red fadeOut_ 2- The other red fadeIn
3- And when I click to anywhere else like the background all the red fadeIn

Answer (score 0):

I've just updated your fiddle and this should do the trick:

```
$(function(){

    $(".green").click(function() {
        $(this).siblings(".red").fadeOut("slow");
        $(this).parents('.photo').siblings().children(".red").fadeIn("slow");
    });

})​
```

Comment: I try this and don't solve what I ask. Perhaps there is something I don't understand?

Answer (score 0):

```
      $(".green").click(function() {
            //Show all red
            $('.red').fadeIn();
            //fade only this
            $(this).siblings(".red").fadeOut("slow");
            });

// click anywhere
        $(document).bind('click', function(e) {
                var $clicked = $(e.target);
                if (! $clicked.hasClass("green"))
                { 
                   $('.red').fadeIn();
                }
            });
```

Comment: Your code works perfect. Thank you. I don't understand how does the part "click anywhere" works. Can you explain it please?

Comment: I bind the click event for all the document element, and I test the clicked element with `e.target`, Note that `e.target` return the clicked dom element while `$(e.target)` return the jQuery Object for this element.

Comment: 1. If I understand this part says: if the ones not clicked have the class green, red fadeIn. Is that correct?

Comment: 2. e.target here has the same function than "this" (in this case not this or !this). Would It be the same?

Comment: @Narcis, this condition return true if the clicked element hasn't the green class ( in other way all the elements except the green one.), e.target refer to the clicked elements but this refer to the document element, so isn't the same